# This Ajax works with debugging (Firebug), but not without it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

When I debug is code in Firebug, it works fine - it inserts records in my database and redirects to a URL. But it doesn't work. It gives me an error, `alert('error')`, when I don't use a debugger. Why? `val` is a serialized array,

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
    if (validation == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some url",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: val,
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});​

//PHP Code
$return['url']= "/index.php?action=jobSeeker/jobSeekerRegistrationConfirmation";
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($return).");";
```

Comment: The error function gets passed three paramters. One of them (the last one) will probably tell you what the problem actally is. Also, if you're in the debugger, use network sniffing to actually work out what's being passed back.

Answer (score 2):

You said when this behaves correctly, you direct the user to a new URL. If that's the case, could this be an issue of your form submitting and redirecting to a new page before your JS success call has a chance to execute?

If you change

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
```

to

```
$('#target').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

your $.ajax success callback should run, then you will need to continue the URL redirect with the help of JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this,

You are making the `POST` request with `ajax`, but in php

```
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($return).");";
```

looking for a `$_GET`, hence the response would not be a valid `jsonp` formatted one. Though the execution will update the database. This is the reason to get the error.
The redirection will also be successful, since it is not having any relationship with `ajax success`.